# Insert missing values in categorized style

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style

In QGIS Bonn, when styling my layer to use the categorize option, I want to have all values within a range, for instance, 0 to 50000.

I am using the data from a CSV that has information about population density and I am using a grayscale to categorize it.

But the values are so different that 0 is white, 2000 is medium gray and 50000 is black.

This does not reflect the true differences between population per area and I do not want to add the missing integer values by hand, how do I do it?

Comment: A screenshot could be helpful. Also, you can change breaks as this example https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcS1k.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you take 'graduated' instead of 'categorized', you can choose the number of classes.  Eg 5 classes gives you

0-10000

10000-20000

20000-30000

etc.

Answer (score 1):

A way to overcome this kind of problem is to use a non-linear reclassification of the data (for exemple using the square root of the value for representation, or log or exp or... depending of the actual distribution of the data).

By reclassifying you could differentiate more at one end of the scale (for exemple square root will let you discriminate between low value by lowering more the high value than the low one)